# White space between image and td when zooming in or out in the browser

Tags: css, html-table, whitespace, zooming

I browsed some other questions, but couldn't find something that fixes my issue.

I created a code snippet here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/manoj382/3SeB7/embedded/result/

I have a table with one row and six cells. The width of each td/cell is defined and it matches the width of the image inside of it (the width of each image is defined, too). Everything works fine, but when I zoom in or out in the browser, white gaps appear somewhat sporadically.

I tried removing white space in the code, I defined the width and height, the images are set to display:block, the total width of each cell/image matches the total width of the entire table, which is also defined. The client is being picky about the gaps when zooming, though, and I'm out of ideas.

*This is for an HTML newsletter, which is why I'm using the old school table layout method.

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="31">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/31/64" style="width:31px; height:64px;">
            </td>

            <td width="65">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/65/64" style="width:65px; height:64px;">
            </td>

            <td width="411">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/411/64" style="width:411px; height:64px;">
            </td>

            <td width="64">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/64/64" style="width:64px; height:64px;">
            </td>

            <td width="29">
                <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/29/64" style="width:29px; height:64px;">
            </td>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The relevant css:

```
<style type="text/css">
    img {display:block !important;}
</style>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by zooming through.   I look at the page and it looks fine.   I went to iphone and did some zooming in and out and see no gaps.  What browser is creating gaps?

Comment: I was able to reproduce on FF mac, chrome mac, and IE. I'm using the browser's zoom method (ctrl+, ctrl-). Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I can't really help.   On the PC, it does not happen on IE or Chrome, but, does happen in a very minor way (1 px) on FF.   To Kludge a fix on the PC problem, you could backfill the cells with black.  The only place the problem appears is next to the black right border of the cat.  A black fill would cover the problem.  But, I can not imagine how the problem would be fixed.   This is a browser/system specific problem.

Comment: Actually, in the vain of the above comment, you could use each image as a background for the cell it is in and place the image on-top of the background. That might improve the blending where the image does not position quite correctly on the right or left border.

Comment: @user1760422 Yeah, I was tossing around the idea of using background images, but the cats code was an example - my actual images are part of a larger, sliced up graphic so unfortunately the bg (even revealing just 1px) is noticeable.

Comment: I ended up using background images. Even though it's not a perfect fix, the problem is far less noticeable since the gaps aren't just white anymore. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While zooming in/out, the browser has to round the box widths to integers. You cannot assume that things will always be properly aligned.

One solution could be to use `float: left` boxes instead of table cells so that the boxes are always guaranteed to be flush against each other.

Another solution could be to use background images instead of `<img>` tags as @user1760422 mentioned in a comment above. You could make the images slightly wider than the cells or just allow `background-repeat: repeat-x` to show a patch of pixels instead of a white strip between the images.

Comment: Thanks, Ates. Your explanation is exactly what I passed on to the client. From further googling I think it is indeed a browser-related issue. @user1760422's background images suggestion is what I used to nix the white gaps and make the issue less apparent.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain why it's doing this (I'm able to duplicate it on my Mac).  But I do have a fix.

For some reason, your table cell with the width of 411 pixels is showing as 412px wide.  The image is also showing as 412px wide, even though the image itself is only 411px wide.  You can see this if you run Chrome Dev Tools and mouse over the table cell.  It will show that it has an actual width of 412 for some reason that I cannot explain.

If I delete the table width of 600 at the top, the problem goes away.

Change this:

```
<table width="600" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

to:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/3SeB7/1/embedded/result/

Comment: Hi manishie, yeah I was coming across the same bug when inspecting with the chrome inspector.. I still don't understand why it shows as 412 instead of 411. Your jsfiddle works, which I don't understand either. The weird thing is that in your example the cells add up to 600, but when you inspect the table it says it's 599. I tried this out anyway, but in my actual code it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is your sliced images are sometimes odd integers. If you change the image slice widths to an even number (and of course in the widths in the img and td tags), it should eliminate the gaps at certain zoom levels.

Answer (score 0):

insted of giving width in the table, try giving the width in the style tag:

Insted of

Try the below

`<table style="width:700px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">`

Answer (score -1):

I just had a similar issue. What the browser is doing is increasing the `<td>` cells so that combined they fill the whole width of the table, which is causing the white space between the image which is `XXpx` and the td which is now `XX.2313px`. You can fix this by setting the `min-width` of all your images to `100%`.